# maven build fails with message in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, maven-3, jenkins-plugins

I am running a Jenkins server version 2.36, and intermittently, I am getting these failures when building a maven project:
I searched around, there are many experiencing this problem, but no one really knows what is causing it. Any ideas?
The error is the following:

```
ERROR: Aborted Maven execution for InterruptedIOException
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory$SocketHandler$AcceptorImpl.accept(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:320)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:295)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:254)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:324)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:63)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at ......remote call to Channel to /10.0.9.100(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1537)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:253)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:822)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:256)
    at hudson.maven.$Proxy66.accept(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory.newProcess(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:282)
    at hudson.maven.ProcessCache.get(ProcessCache.java:236)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:798)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1729)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:544)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98) 
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
```

Comment: Which version maven plugin do you use? Which version of Maven are you using? Does that happen always on the same node? Which JDK are you running Jenkins ? How have you connected the nodes?

Comment: Just guessing: "/10.0.9.100" -> is this slash normal here and IP accessible?

Comment: Do you know what kind of service is is running on this machine 10.0.9.100?

Comment: any luck in finding an answer? I have the same problem (although much shorter stack trace because I have only one node) and it looks like jenkins is trying to fork maven process on port which is for some reason not acceptable. Look at the command one line above the stacktrace... at the end there is a port number... restarting a build solves the issue, but not for me... I need to have a stable CI env without any false positives... anybody knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable IPv6 by adding `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to jenkins.xml  `arguments` tag.

Comment: @khmarbaise On Jenkins server maven-plugin 2.14 and java 1.7.0_65.
the nodes are connected to Jenkins via swarm plugin since there are aws nodes, and each time a new is created.

Comment: I gave it a try, but the problem still occurs intermittently, as it was

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this seems to be caused by some kind of memory and/or CPU usage problem. I was repeatedly getting this error message whilst building my maven application through jenkins whilst on a `t2.micro` ec2-instance on AWS.

The solution was to change my instance from `t2.micro` to `t2.medium` (small may have worked but untested). Not the best solution I'm sure, but I think the error stems from CPU maxing capacity - which was the one consistent factor when this issue occurred.